# Add and remove classes does not work in jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

I have the following code generate sheet:

```
function generatePage(idexp, numero) {
    console.log(doc);
    html = '';
    var est1 = 'iwfa';
    for (var i = 0; i < numero; i++) {
        ...
        html += '           <i class="fa fa-upload '+est1+'" id="imp' + i + '" title="Importar" style="color:'+impcolor+'"></i>';
        html += '           <i class="fa fa-upload '+est2+'" id="des' + i + '" title="Importar" style="color:'+impcolor2+'"></i>';
        ...
    } //fin for

    $('.iwfa').click(function (we) {
        xid = $(we.target).attr('id');
        var cls = $.grep(classNames, function(c,i) {
            return $.inArray(c,classes) !== -1; //retorna cuál icono fue clikado
        });

        if(cls == 'fa-upload'){
            $('#dialog-fabrica').dialog('open');
        } else if ( cls == 'fa-edit') {
            $('#dialog-describir').dialog('open');
        }
    });
}

$("#dialog-fabrica").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 200,
    width: 360,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Cancelar": function () {
            $("#dialog-fabrica").trigger('reset');
            $(this).dialog("close");
        },
        "Guardar": function () {
            if ($('#wformregister').valid()) {
                addDocDetalle();    
                $('#imp' + $('#hident').val()).removeClass('iwfa');
                $('#des' + $('#hident').val()).addClass('iwfa');
                $(this).dialog('close');
            }
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        $("#dialog-fabrica").trigger('reset');
    }
});
```

I open the dialogue and by the "Guardar" option I add and remove the class. I checked the Chrome console and did the addition and deletion of the classes, but when clicking it does not work.

Please Help me

Comment: Maybe execution never gets to those lines. Does the `Guardar` function fire? Is the valid check true? Does `addDocDetalle()` work properly?

Comment: Do you know how to set a breakpoint in the JavaScript debugger? Set a breakpoint on the `if` statement, then single-step through the code to see if it's running.

Comment: Is it closing the dialog when you click that button?

Comment: Could you put your code HTML + JS in a codepen or jsfiddle please ?

Comment: addDocDetalle() work, removeClass and addClass also work, this is verified in the chrome console, but when doing the click event, it does not work. I can not add in jsfiddle, because it's a very large process